# Kullback-Leibler Divergence in python with categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am comparing two distributions of categorical data. I have a SQL table, converted into a data frame, which I am then using get counts of the values in each category. But rather than do the process manually, I'm not seeing much support or a canonical way to do this. Of course, if I compare two distributions, I want the bins to be ordered and be identical across both distributions. Rather than do this very manually.

Is there a smart way I can make the distributions created share the same categorical bins? One of the distributions looks like:

```
engines = df[df['engine'] == 'unity']['category'].value_counts()
print(engines)
np.histogram(engines, density=True)
```

The data at the end looks like the following:

```
cat 1                 99940
cat 2                 44259
cat 3                 225
cat 4                 31
Name: engine, dtype: int64
```

and this is duplicated for another query to that there are two distributions that can be compared. But I can find no way to ensure that we have unified categories across multiple distributions.

once I have the two distributions, the following KLD can happen:

```
scipy.special.kl_div(engines, engines_two)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are asking just:

```
pd.crosstab(df['category'], df['engine'])
```

you may want to throw in `normalize='column'` to the function. And then you can have your distributions as columns.

Comment: Thanks. I am having a little play but finding the issue: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (15) into shape (4971755)

Comment: I have attempted also by serializing or with  lists, but not having the expected output.